# Changing bg Image via Jquery very slow on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slowdown

I´m having a problem changing the bg image from a div. It works on Google Chrome and Firefox flawlessly but on IE it hangs a little bit. It´s pretty slow on IE, and sometimes it doest even load the image properly. my jquery code is:

```
$("a.preview").click(function(e){
    var carregar = new Image();
    $(carregar).attr('src','imagens/logos/' +  this.id +'.jpg');
    var img = "imagens/logos/" +  this.id +".jpg"; // recebe src da imagem de acordo com a ID
    var alvo = this.id; // salva ID do disparador
    var logo = document.createElement('img'); // cria objeto imagem
    var $logoCarregado = $(logo); // recebe o objeto imagem criado
    $logoCarregado.attr('src', 'imagens/logos/'+ alvo +'_logo.png'); //define atributo src da imagem criada

    $(".box").fadeOut("fast");
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".overlay").hide("fast");
    $(".logo").hide("fast");
    $(".logo").empty();

    $(".loader").show("fast"); // mostra carregamento
    $(carregar).load( function() { // carrega o conteudo
       $(".loader").hide("fast"); // esconde imagem de carregamento
       $(".logo").empty(); // apaga conteúdo da ID logo
       $("#menu").fadeOut("fast"); //fadeOut menu   
       $(".overlay").show("fast"); // mostra barra do conteúdo da página do cliente     
       $(".logo").show("fast"); // mostra logo do cliente
       $logoCarregado.appendTo('.logo'); // atribue a logo do cliente á div logo
       $("#fundo").empty();
      $("#fundo").append("<img src='"+ img +"' class='bg' />"); // troca o fundo
       var logoHeight = $logoCarregado.height() + 100; // seta o tamanho da logo + 80 como altura

      if (logoHeight <= 120){ //verifica posição do logo do cliente

       $(".box" + "#"+alvo) // seleciona o box de texto de acordo com a ID do disparador
            .css("display", + "block") // mostra o box
            .css("left","0%") // define distância da margem esquerda do box
            .fadeIn("fast") // fadeIn texto
            .css("top",+ logoHeight+100 + 'px'); // define altura do box
        $(".box" + "#"+alvo).animate({ 
            left: '8%'}, 300 ); // anima entrada do texto
      }
      else{

           $(".box" + "#"+alvo) // seleciona o box de texto de acordo com a ID do disparador
            .css("display", + "block") // mostra o box
            .css("left","0%") // define distância da margem esquerda do box
            .fadeIn("fast") // fadeIn texto
            .css("top",+ logoHeight + 'px'); // define altura do box
        $(".box" + "#"+alvo).animate({ 
            left: '8%'}, 300 ); // anima entrada do texto
      }

      });
return false;
    });
```

Website: [link](http://www.zecaconsoni.com.br/ftp/novo/clientes.html)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to optimize the code is trying to minimize JQuery selector usage, by reusing them.

So, instead of using this:

```
$(".box").fadeOut("fast");
$(".box").hide();
$(".overlay").hide("fast");
$(".logo").hide("fast");
$(".logo").empty();
```

Try this...

```
var $boxElem = $('.box');
var $logoElem = $('.logo');

$boxElem.fadeOut("fast").hide();
$(".overlay").hide("fast");
$logoElem.hide("fast").empty();
```

Or even better...

```
var boxElem = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
```

Comment: Tks a lot for the tip micadelli! Looks like it´s working better now after the changes you suggested but it still does not run as smooth as it is on chrome for example. A preview can be found here: http://www.zecaconsoni.com.br/ftp/novo/clientes.html is there anyway to optimize the loading time of those images? Adding a preload would make it slower since it would have to load every bg image right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those seems to be pretty huge images you're loading... I would probably make it so that it starts loading them after 'clients' page is fully loaded, and maybe adding some sort of progress bar some where on page.. that's my 2 cents

Comment: The image have an average weight of 400kb each, I thought the problem would be in the code I wrote, but since nobody pointed it out, I assume it´s correct, what makes me confuse is why does Chrome, Safari and Firefox present the page as it should be, but IE does not. Having a preload being executed after the page is displayed should i use document.load or .ready? Tks again

Answer (score 0):

It depends what exactly is slow. It may be caused by:

- DOM change
- backgroud-image downloading

jQuery slows down the browser by design. To achieve really fast page, don't use jQuery.

It is worth to preload the image:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'image.png';
```

Then you can just switch CSS classes:

```
.mode1 {
    background-image: url(default.png);
}

.mode2 {
    background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

by ECMAscript:

```
document.getElementById('logo').className = 'mode2';
```

Comment: Václav I dont know how to explain it but the "feeling" of it being slow or getting stuck somewhere just happens when I use IE. Otherwise its completely fine. I wonder if it is something wrong with my code or its just an standard behavior on IE. Did you access the link I´ve posted? Preloading every single image would not help because the user would have to wait a lot (every image is 400kb). And since my BG only changes when the user click at a link i thought it would be faster doing it using Jquery and I have some other animations being executed together. Tks a lot for the reply tho.

Comment: I visited your page and traced network communication. Opera loads all images pointed by CSS on page load. IE loads them when they are needed. You have to preload images after page is loaded. User wouldn not have to wait then.

Comment: So a preload script would be triggered on document.load or document.ready?

Comment: Yes. The image is downloaded when you set `src` property of `Image` object. When you set this property in function called on `document.load` you will not increase page load time, because those images will be loaded in background after page is fully loaded.

Comment: Great I´ve found a preloading script here and added on my script which  made the page navigate faster, altho, I´m not happy with its performance yet, dunno if it can be improved. I´ve seen a lot of people having the same issue with bg image on IE, so it might be an engine problem rather an error on my code. I appreciate all the help from you and others. I´m a designer not a programer/developer so all your help were more than appreciated! Tks a lot Václav